# MVC multilanguage project turns back to default language

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, globalization

I want to change navbar titles acording to the choosen language but when i click any title at the navbar, language goes back to default language which is english

navbar

```
        <div class="navbar-links">
            <ul>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink(drbilginbilgilimultilanguage.Resources.Language.Home, "Index", "Website")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink(drbilginbilgilimultilanguage.Resources.Language.About, "About", "Website")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink(drbilginbilgilimultilanguage.Resources.Language.Gallery, "Gallery", "Website")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink(drbilginbilgilimultilanguage.Resources.Language.Contact, "Contact", "Website")</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Choosing language dropup button

```
    <div class="btn-group dropup" style="position:fixed; left: 2px; bottom: 2px; ">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Language
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="" class="dropdown-item"> @Html.ActionLink("Türkçe", "Index", "Language", new { language = "tr" },null)</a>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">@Html.ActionLink("English", "Index", "Language", new { language = "en" }, null)</a>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">@Html.ActionLink("Deutsche", "Index", "Language", new { language = "de" }, null)</a>

        </div>
    </div>
```

language controller

```
        // GET: Language
        public ActionResult Index(string language)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(language))
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);

            }
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Languages");
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            return Redirect("Website/Index");
        }
```

Global.asax

```
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Languages"];
            if (cookie != null && cookie.Value != null)
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cookie.Value);
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, it might be better to include the language code (en) for example in the URL and use routing to set and get the language, and it's a lot better for SEO

Comment: I just want to make globalization work i actually don't care how its done. If that is a better way to do it, how can i learn it. I am new at the mvc stuff.